# Grouping while adding previous row value into next

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I am storing leave information of employees and I want to calculate total leaves employee have taken so far after taking every leave.
I have tried query but it is not grouping for each employee instead it keeps on adding all the previous rows values.

```
CREATE TABLE SampleLeave
(
ID Numeric,
EmpCode Numeric, 
NoOfLeaves Numeric
);


INSERT INTO SampleLeave VALUES (1, 12, 2);
INSERT INTO SampleLeave VALUES (2, 12, 1);
INSERT INTO SampleLeave VALUES (3, 12, 3);
INSERT INTO SampleLeave VALUES (4, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO SampleLeave VALUES (5, 1, 5);

SELECT *, SUM([NoOfLeaves]) OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) Leaves FROM SampleLeave
```

Here is the output I am getting instead I want the Sum function to calculate the number of leaves when employee ID differs.

```
ID                                      EmpCode                                 NoOfLeaves                              Leaves
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1                                       12                                      2                                       2
2                                       12                                      1                                       3
3                                       12                                      3                                       6
4                                       1                                       1                                       7
5                                       1                                       5                                       12
```

Output I am expecting:

```
ID                                      EmpCode                                 NoOfLeaves                              Leaves
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1                                       12                                      2                                       2
2                                       12                                      1                                       3
3                                       12                                      3                                       6
4                                       1                                       1                                       1
5                                       1                                       5                                       6
```

Comment: Just add Partition by. SUM([NoOfLeaves]) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY [ID]) Leaves FROM SampleLeave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would required to add `partition` clause in order to get *departmental*   leaves based on `EmpCode`

```
select *, 
        sum([NoOfLeaves]) over (partition by EmpCode order by id) Leaves 
from SampleLeave
order by 1
```